# Return NA for division

Tags: r, na, inf

I am trying to define a new variable that is the division of two other variables.

```
df$NewVariable <- df$OldVariable1 / (df$OldVariable2/100)
```

`OldVariable2` contains `NA`s. I'd like `NewVariable` to return `NA`s, whenever `OldVariable2` is `NA`. However, when I do `summmary(df$NewVariable)` after creating it, I get average and maximum of `Inf`. How can I tell R to produce `NA`s, so that my new `NewVariable` isn't affected by any `Inf`s?

Comment: Looks like at least one value in `df$OldVariable2` is `0`.

Comment: The default is that `NA`s are propagated by division as you are asking for. `Inf` values are created when you divide by 0 -- they don't have anything to do with `NA` values.

Comment: As mentioned, one of the values in df$OldVariable2 is 0, in that case, what value do you want? NA or Inf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df <- data.frame(OldVariable1 = c(2,3,4,4),
                 OldVariable2 = c(3,NA,0,1.5))
df$NewVariable <- ifelse(df$OldVariable2 == 0, NA, 
                         df$OldVariable1 / (df$OldVariable2/100))
```

Result:

```
> df
  OldVariable1 OldVariable2 NewVariable
1            2          3.0    66.66667
2            3           NA          NA
3            4          0.0          NA
4            4          1.5   266.66667
```

Thanks to @Gregor Thomas he pointed out that when you divide a number by NA, or NA/NA you'll get NA, so it wasn't necessary the first condition and you can simplify it.

Comment: This won't solve the problem - division already propagates `NA` values. If OP is getting `Inf` values the problem is 0s in the denominator, not missing values.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the flaw of my answer @GregorThomas

Comment: Much improved! The `is.na(df$OldVariable2)` is redundant - `x / NA` will give `NA` for all `x` already. You can simplify to `ifelse(df$OldVariable2 == 0, NA, df$OldVariable1 / (df$OldVariable2/100))`

Comment: Thank you @GregorThomas, I started typing in the console `3/NA` and `NA/NA` to see what I get... it's `NA`!